# How to find out framerate of JW Player video on client computer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, jwplayer

We need to display the framerate of a video that user is watching with JW Player. We have already tried tried everything with JW Player 7 API but it doesn't give us the client side frame rate.

We have built a JW Player plugin which is supposed to calculate the framerate on every ENTER_FRAME event while the video is playing.

We are listening to ENTER_FRAME event on line 61.
api.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, calculateFPS);

Everytime a new frame is entered the plugin executes calculateFPS function. The framerate is displayed in a textbox.

For some reason the calculated framerate is around 30 fps. This cannot be possible because the original framerate of the video is 15 fps. 
I think that the problem might be on line 61 where the eventlistener is listening to the player instead of the video. Is it possible to link the eventlistener straight to the video?

Here is the whole plugin actionscript code. It is based on a JW Player plugin example APITester.as.

```
package {
import com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.events.*;
import com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.player.*;
import com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.plugins.*;

import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.Event; 

import flash.utils.getTimer;

/** An example plugin that tests various player integrations. **/
public class APITester extends Sprite implements IPlugin6 {

    [Embed(source="mute.png")]
    private const MuteIcon:Class;

    private var api:IPlayer;
    private var field:TextField;

    private var clickButton:Sprite;

    public var startTime:Number;
    public var framesNumber:Number = 0;
    public var fps:TextField = new TextField();


    /** Let the player know what the name of your plugin is. **/
    public function get id():String {
        return "apitester";
    };

    public function get target():String {
        return "6.0";
    }


    /** Constructor **/
    public function APITester() {
        clickButton = new Sprite();
        clickButton.addChild(new MuteIcon());
        clickButton.y = 10;
        clickButton.buttonMode = true;
        addChild(clickButton);


         startTime = getTimer();
        addChild(fps);


    };


    /** Called by the player after the plugin has been created. **/
    public function initPlugin(player:IPlayer, config:PluginConfig):void {

        api = player;

        api.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, calculateFPS); 

        api.play();



    };

    private function calculateFPS(evt:Event):void {

        var currentTime:Number = (getTimer() - startTime) / 1000;

        framesNumber++;

        if (currentTime > 1)
        {
            fps.text = "FPS: " + (Math.floor((framesNumber/currentTime)*10.0)/10.0);

            startTime = getTimer();
            framesNumber = 0;
        }   
    };

    /** If the player resizes itself, this gets called (including on setup). **/
    public function resize(wid:Number, hei:Number):void {
        clickButton.x = wid - 50;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: A SWF's framerate is based upon the stage's `frameRate` and this is `defaulted` to 24 'fps' unless you supply a different one via a compiler option or add a class attribute to your main (entry-point) class, or change it at runtime. So assuming the defaults, your code should report 24fps no matter what the video frame rate is rendering at. If you force software decoding for the video you could monitor the render event but that is highly limiting your clients ability to play video without stuttering.

Comment: The Flash runtime plays video content at its native frame rate, regardless of the frame rate of the application and I personally do not know of any events that is dispatched based on on the software or hardware acceleration of a single video frame...

Comment: `Everytime a new frame is entered the plugin executes calculateFPS function.` You're assuming `enterFrame` is about the video but really it's about the SWF itself, ie: how often it refreshes (or updates) animations and texts etc. As @SushiHangover pointed out, Flash will try to decode at the video's own framerate. If it cant keep up it just drops frames. Look at this **[NetstreamInfo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStreamInfo.html)** then find the netstream code in JW  Player to add any features that your **api = player** variable can access

Comment: Whatever is attached to a NetStream in JW code you reference that in your `enterFrame` code. If you know the original FPS of video just minus the dropped frames and that should give you how much true FPS the client can handle per sec (this FPS might change from time to time). Something like... `client_FPS = (vidFPS - ns.info.droppedFrames)`. Also there is a `ns.decodedFrames` which you can put in a timer that checks the number every 1000ms like `client_FPS = ns.decodedFrames - lastDecodedTotal` then also update last Total to the new decodedFrames amount ready for next timer cycle.

Comment: I think its **[this AS file](https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/blob/master/src/flash/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/media/VideoMediaProvider.as)** you have to edit. There the `ns.decodedFrames` becomes like their netstream setup which becomes `_stream.decodedFrames` but gawd knows.. Good luck.

Comment: Why not just using [`NetStream.currentFPS`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#currentFPS) ?

Comment: Yeah, that would work too. Problem is how to also reference that NetStream as defined in the other **.as** Class in his main code which uses other middle man Classes. Maybe the Asker already solved that part though...